# using android pre-populate database by using select query . how to do it?

Tags: android, select, android-sqlite

this is the first time that i use pre-populate database that mean the database must be displayed in the **oncreate method** .
and i need to use the select query  to perform the SQL queries i read many tutorial that display the steps to get the pre populated database.

if anyone can help me  i will appreciate that.

this is the code that i use it from several tutorial

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        // ******* to copy database prepopulate the application*************//
        // ********************************************************************//

        private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.devleb.database/world_cup";
        public static String DATABASE_NAME = "world_cup";
        private SQLiteDatabase db;
        private final Context myContext;

        // ******* to copy database prepopulate the application*************//

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            this.myContext = context;
        }

        public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

            if (dbExist) {

            } else {
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                try {
                    copyDataBase();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new Error("Error copying Data");
                }
            }

        }

        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // Open your local db as the input stream
            InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

            // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

            // Open the empty db as the output stream
            OutputStream myOutPut = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutPut.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            myOutPut.flush();
            myOutPut.close();
            myInput.close();

        }


        public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }

        public synchronized void  close(){
            if(db != null){
                db.close();
            }
        }
        private boolean checkDataBase() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
            try {
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

            } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            }
            if (checkDB != null) {
                checkDB.close();
            }

            return checkDB != null ? true : false;

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
            //_db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version "
                    + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
                    + ", which will destroy all old data!");
            // Destroy old database:
            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            // Recreate new database:
            onCreate(_db);
        }
    }
```

what i need is to add a select query to select what i need because i have more than one table to be prepopulated .

Answer (score -1):

then create model class(also called Bean)for each table and methods like this for each table

```
public static ArrayList<ModelTable1> SelectAll() {
    SQLiteDatabase sqldb = //initialize database here;
    ArrayList<ModelTable1> arrModelList = null;
    Cursor cursor = null;
    String Query = "Select * from " + TableName;
    cursor = sqldb.rawQuery(Query, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        arrModelList = new ArrayList<ModelTable1>();
        do {
            ModelTable1 model = new ModelTable1();

            model.Id = (cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("ID")));
            model.name = (cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("NAME")));
            arrModelList.add(model);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
    }// end if(cursor!=null)
    return arrModelList;
}
```

**Edit**

```
class ModelTable1{
  String Id;
  String name;
}
```

Comment: i did not understand your answer **then create model class(also called Bean)**    what is **ModelTable1** ?? can you explain more your answer ?